# Двойной необычный запрос к mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Есть таблица 1, в ней есть определенные id. Есть таблица 2, в нее попадают записи у которых поле `connect`='id' (id из таблицы 1). Можно ли как то 1м запросом узнать какого `connect` нет во второй таблице?

пример:

```
//таблица 1
id    num    dig
1     5      6
5     7      8
8     15     6
9     1      5

//таблица 2
id    connect    dig
5     2          0
6     5          1
7     1          15    
9     9          3
```

берем из первой таблицы id - 1,5,8,9, ищем их во второй - по `connect`. В итоге должно выдать, что во второй таблице нет 1,8

```
//результат такого запроса
id    num    dig
1     5      6
8     15     6
```

Ну, и если такое сделать нельзя прошу тоже сказать. Нет - тоже ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SELECT * FROM  `t1` WHERE `t1`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `connect` FROM  `t2`)
2. SELECT t1.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.connect = t1.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL

Comment: Не знал! Теперь буду знать. Спасибо